# Proving a function is well defined and differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^{+}_{0}$ with $a<1$ and $ab<1$. Show that the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as:
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^n\cos(b^n\pi x) $$

is well defined and differentiable.

I know that to show a function is well defined I have to show $x = y \implies f(x) = f(y)$. I get stuck on showing that the function is differentiable. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Search for "differentiation term by term"

Comment: In this case well defined means, that the sum converges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well defined means the series converges for every $x$ so that $f(x)$ is indeed a real number. Convergence follows by comparing with $\sum a^{n}$.
 Now let $s_n(x)= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a^{k} \cos(b^{k}\pi x)$. Then $s_n \to f$ uniformly. Also, $s_n'(x)=-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (ab)^{k} \pi  \sin(b^{k}\pi x)$ and this also converges uniformly since the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} (ab)^{k}   \sin(b^{k}\pi x)$ is uniformly convergent (by comparison with $\sum (ab)^{k}$). Let the limit of $s_n'$ be $g$. Then, taking limits in the equation $s_n(x)=s_n(0)+\int_0^{x} s_n'(t)dt$ we get $f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^{x} g(t)dt$. Since $g$ is continuous it follows that $f$ is differentiable.